# how to convert a string into a directory? boost on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-filesystem

I am having trouble converting a path into a directory on Linux using a boost. below is my code, this directory exists in my folder but somehow not recognised as directory as it always print out PATH DOES NOT EXISTS

i am guessing this is a linux problem because the same code works fine on windows visual studio 2015

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    boost::filesystem::path p ("/home/dj/tut");
    cout <<p.generic_string()<<endl;
    if (boost::filesystem::is_directory(p)) { cout << "PATH EXISTS " << endl; }else { cout << "PATH DOES NOT EXISTS" << endl; }
}
```

how i compile with

```
g++ -I /home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost script.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

and then do the following to run:

```
./test
```

with `ldd test` i get :

```
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007ffc8cdb9000) 
libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007fef36573000)
libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007fef3636f000) 
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fef35fed000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fef35dd7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fef35a0d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fef357f0000) 
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fef354e7000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fef3678b000)
```

Comment: When you refer to the code running fine on windows, this is with a different value of  your variable `p`, right?

Comment: If output is only "PATH DOES NOT EXISTS", then clearly p is somehow empty, when it is printed.

Comment: @lubgr yes it is with the path on windows. the path was ".\\tut" but it doesn't work on Linux

Comment: @hyde yea but cout <<p.generic_string()<<endl; does print out /home/dj/tut hmm...

Comment: For my OS(manjaro) it's works.

Comment: Can you check the output of `ls -ld /home/dj/tut`?

Comment: Then, what does command *file /home/dj/tut* show?

Comment: @lubgr shows  drwxrwxr-x

Comment: @hyde it shows  /home/dj/tut :directory

Comment: @MichałKalinowski whats your OS? i am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: manjaro - arch based linux

Comment: Did you check for error messages?

Comment: Your code works for me (Ubuntu 18.04 and Boost 1.62 provided by apt). Try it with Ubuntu's own boost. If that works, then your problem becomes, what is difference between that and this Boost you installed manually.

Comment: As a guess, your header file is from Boost 1.65, but the libraries which end up being used are from Ubuntu (and as such, much older).

Comment: I am with @hyde. In fact that's worth an answer. OP, can you investigate with `ldd test` after compile/linking with the command shown?

Comment: @hyde by "Ubuntu's own boost" u meant the one i get via sudo apt-get? i get this when i try to install boost via apt-get the following:
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1). 
does it mean this boost is already the system one?

Comment: @sehe i get the following:

 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc8cdb9000)
 libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007fef36573000)
 libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007fef3636f000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fef35fed000)

Comment: libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fef35dd7000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fef35a0d000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fef357f0000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fef354e7000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fef3678b000)

Comment: Yup, so there's your problem indeed. The answer is correct. (Maybe edit the question next time, instead of dumping that into comments :))

Comment: @sehe hmm but it still doesnt work for me ...:(
still printing out path does not exist

Comment: Use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, make sure you have **built** the libraries you use. Alternatively, use the -rpath linker option (easy to check using `ldd` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set correctly)

Comment: @sehe i tried using LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still doesnt work :(. i think i have built the libraries .. how do i check for sure that i have built them properly?

Comment: If you are fine with Ubuntu's own boost, then just remove the `-I<path to different boost>` from the compilation. Since you have the -dev package, it should find the headers and compile. If it still does not work, then there's something funny going on.

Comment: @DJ_ that's what I meant earlier "(easy to check using ldd with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set correctly)" - the comment was a little too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you specify the include file search path only, without `-L` to have matching libraries linked:

```
g++ -I /home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost script.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

If that compiles, then linker and runtime is using Ubuntu's boost libraries. Now I have no idea how this could produce the effect you get, but funny things can happen when you mix versions like this.

Try compiling something like this (fix paths as needed) to make linker search your own version of the libs:

```
g++ -I /home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost script.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -L/home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

Then to use correct library at run time, you can use this (note, single command line):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost ./test
```

Or something like that, you get the idea I hope.

Comment: hmm it still doesn't work for me after following this.
i tired to re install my boost and i get the following :

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/dj/boost_1_65_1

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/dj/boost_1_65_1/stage/lib
does it mean that my boost is correctly installed? (although still doesn't work)

Comment: Your boost is probably installed correctly, if you installed it to your home directory (and not to `/usr/lib` or something). As implied, there are 3 things to consider: correct header files (used during compilation, set by `-I`), .so library files checked by linker (used during linking your project, set by `-L`), and then finally the libraries used when you launch the program (most conveniently set by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable). These all must match (or at least be compatible versions), or there is a chance of funny things happening (or just an error message if you are lucky).

Comment: As explained in those other comments, *ldd* is the righ tool for checking which .so files are used at runtime. You can also `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` if you don't want to give it before every command like shown in the answer.

Comment: managed to get the correct output:) i deleted the boost in my system so that it stop linking to the system bash and manage to get it running hahah anw for mine to run, the boost path in  g++ -I /home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost script.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -L/home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system i needed to link to /home/dj/boost_1_65_1 instead of /home/dj/boost_1_65_1/boost

Comment: THANK ALL FOR HELPING ME!!:D